# core dumped because of improperly included library

Tags: c++, qt, valgrind, ros

When I run my code I get

```
Bus error(core dumped)
```

When I run it with valgrind I get

```
==26570== Invalid read of size 8
==26570==    at 0x67EDEE6: ??? (in /home/carolinaloureiro/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5SerialPort.so.5.4.0)
==26570==    by 0x67F34CB: ??? (in /home/carolinaloureiro/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5SerialPort.so.5.4.0)
==26570==    by 0x4E3D5F4: classA::function1(bool) (in /home/carolinaloureiro/catkin_ws/src/testpackage/lib/libLIB.so.1)
==26570==    by 0x4E3DC75: OptoPorts_private::run() (in /home/carolinaloureiro/catkin_ws/src/testpackage/lib/libLIB.so.1)
==26570==    by 0x5875383: ??? (in /home/carolinaloureiro/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.4.0)
==26570==    by 0x55BDE99: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==26570==    by 0x65192EC: clone (clone.S:112)
==26570==  Address 0x200000001109da98 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Could this be because I didn't include a library properly? I've been trying to solve this problem for a while but I am no sure how to.

Thanks

Comment: You get [bus error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_error) when you try to access memory not allocated to you. So if I were you, I would look into `classA::function1` to see what it does with any pointers, as well as `OptoPorts_private::run`.

Comment: Both classA::function and OptoPorts_private::run are inside a library I cannot access. I assume there's nothing wrong with these functions so could it be that it has to do with libraries that were not included properly?

Comment: That library, with its *source code*, seems to be in your home-directory (I guess), so why can't you access them? Other than that, how do you create the tread? What arguments do you pass to the thread? Any pointers to memory not accessible to you? Any uninitialized local variables (more specifically pointers) anywhere? Any memory you have allocated and then released but still use? And no it doesn't have anything to do with you including or linking with a library improperly, then you would have gotten build errors.